# .NET 6 : HttpClient work with dynamic json response

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0

I'm using .NET 6. How work with json response from `HttpClient` without declaring a type?

I try do request with dynamic:

```
var http = new HttpClient();
var res = await http.GetAsync("https://api");
var body = await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<dynamic>();
```

In debug mode I see that I get the correct value:

[image]

but then I try get access to field, I get an error

```
body['pagesCount']
```

Comment: I would recommend trying to use `JsonDocument` over `dynamic`.

Comment: @MartinCostello i try var body = await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<JsonDocument>();  body.RootElement['pagesCount']; and receive error : Too many characters in character literal

Comment: That's because you need to use `"` for strings - `'` is for _characters_, so `RootElement["pagesCount"]`.

Comment: okey what about dynamic for use dot notation: body.pagesCount

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `dynamic`.

Comment: All of the above mentioned approaches are super fragile. If the property is not present then they break miserably. If you read it as `JsonDocument` then you have to test its `RootElement`'s `ValueKind` whether it is a `Array` or an `Object`. If latter then you can use [`TryGetProperty` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.trygetproperty?view=net-6.0) to retrieve a property by key.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```cs
var resultType = new { refresh_task = "" }.GetType();
dynamic? result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync(resultType);
```

Comment: what is the point of refresh_task?